# QGIS Line Intersections Plugin does not create a point to some intersection lines

Tags: plugins, qgis, line-intersection

When I use the line intersection plugin in Qgis, it doesn't create whole intersect points. Also, the gif and picture below show that the lines intersect but the plugin doesn't assign any point to them. How can I solve the problem?

[image: picture]

[image: gif]

Comment: Cross-posted as https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/413719/115